# Swift TableView Cell - Show Activity Spinner, Perform Function, Hide Activity Spinner

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am building an application in Swift that shows list of UITableView Cells. When the user taps a cell, I would like the following actions to perform in order:

1. Deselect the row at the index path
2. Show and animate the UIActivitySpinner
3. Perform a function (lasts approximately 10 seconds)
4. Hide the UIActivitySpinner

My current code is as follows:

```
     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

             self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

             let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TableViewCell

             cell.ActivitySpinner.startAnimating()

             myFunction() // Approximately 10 seconds.

             cell.ActivitySpinner.stopAnimating()

             return
        }
```

So the idea is that UIActivitySpinner will appear for 10 seconds while myFunction() executes, and disappear when myFunction() finishes.
 [image]

The current problem is that the UIActivitySpinner only appears once myFunction() has finished executing. I am unsure how to have the ActivitySpinner appear before myFunction() starts, and disappear once myFunction() has finished.

About myFunction(): it is a C function that is linked in the bridging header and is mostly HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all generally it's not a best practise using the first letter of your property in uppercase.

Then this below is not the best solution if you make an asyncronhous thread like a network call..
You can use this function (**I dont recommended this**):

```
func dispatchDelay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

.. and do:

```
cell.ActivitySpinner.startAnimating()
myFunction() // Approximately 10 seconds.
dispatchDelay(10.0) {
     cell.ActivitySpinner.stopAnimating()
}
```

**This is what I suggest to you:**

You must add completion handler to your C function like this example:

```
void myFunction(std::string urlStr, std::function<void(std::string)> callback)
{
  ...
  NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = 
    [defaultSession 
      dataTaskWithURL:url 
      completionHandler:
        ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
          if(error == nil)
          {
             NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);

             // invoke the callback here...
             callback(std::string([text UTF8String]));
          }
        }];
  ...
}
```

And in C you can use it like:

```
void callbackFunc(std::string data)
{
  ...
}

myFunction("...", callbackFunc);
```

What do you need to build now is a cross platform C -> Swift, if you dont know it you can follow these instruction "[Building cross platform aint easy](https://www.syncappate.com/news/Building-cross-platform-aint-easy)": this can permit to you to integrate callback to your swift code to handle the exact myFunction start time and end time.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is great help. Would the completion handler apply to a Obj C BOOL function?

Comment: Sure , you can wrap your c function to obj c and bridge it to swift, this is explained in detail to the link in the answer "Building cross.."